# Angular Contact Bearing Dynamic Loading

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

Does having multiple angular contact bearings together increase the total dynamic loading of the system linearly?

Example: Angular contact bearing with rated dynamic loading at 50kN, thus 3 of them setup together will result in a dynamic loading of 150kN.

See picture for reference.

[image]